# hasOne filtered by value of previous hasOne?

Tags: filter, atk4

In a 'Jobs' table / model, I have two fields using 'hasOne' to pull descriptions from Companies and People tables:

```
$this->hasOne('Companies','companies_id','CompanyName')->caption('Company')
   ->display(array('form'=>'autocomplete/Basic'));
$this->hasOne('People','people_id','DisplayedName')->caption('Contact');
```

My goal is to use the choice made for Companies to filter People to that list who are associated with companies_id. Both Jobs and People have companies_id which would match 'id' in the Companies table.

How best to apply the equivalent filter (for the second item - the Contact) which is equivalent to 'WHERE People.companies_id = Jobs.companies_id'? Is there a form of addCondition to accomplish this?

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: Am I missing something obvious? It seems like it would be necessary to use atk's javascript to fire on the event when Company is changed... to reload the contents of Contact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way how toolkit can do this easily. You would need that on the field level and you can implement a custom validation.

This is from older demos, but you can make it work:

http://demo39.agiletoolkit.org/demo.html?t=20